# Navigation View Controller from Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been working on this problem for a while and thought I would ask for some help. I have 3 view-controllers: 1 Navigation Controller, 1 Main controller and 1 detail view controller.

Within the main view controller, I have a series of subviews with buttons. Due to the class structure, however, I am unable to directly call self.storyboard to get the current storyboard object.

I have tried 2 different methods, a variety of ways, and am still unsuccessful. I posted my methods below and described what is and what is not happening in each segment. The overall goal is to present a child view controller (the detail view) by tapping a button in a subview, of which does not have access to the parent storyboard directly.

**Method 1**

```
//Instantiate the new view controller
ProfileViewViewController *tempViewToShow = [del.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profile"];

// Pass data into the new view controller
tempViewToShow.thisUser = self.postUser;

// Output a simple log to ensure both were created
NSLog(@"Temp User Name: %@, Profile Desc: %@", [tempViewToShow.thisUser getFullName], tempViewToShow.description);

// Using the AppDelegate for the RootViewController, present the detail view
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:tempViewToShow animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

*Issues*
The issue with this series is that the detail view **does not** carry the navigation controller (since it is not mentioned), however, this way still shows a full View Controller

**Method 2**

...

```
 // Use the Delegate and the navigation controller to present the new view controller
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController.navigationController presentViewController:tempViewToShow animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

*Issues*
Does not display anything

**Method 3**

```
// Use the recommended 'pushViewController' for the navigation controller to carry over
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:tempViewToShow animated:NO];
```

*Issues*
Does not display anything

---

En toto, how would I make this work? What lines would I modify and how? Thanks!

Comment: what you want to do ? you want navigation bar ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue like this:

```
ProfileViewViewController *tempViewToShow = [del.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profile"];
UINavigationController *naviController = [[UINavigationController alloc] tempViewToShow];
```

And then do this :

```
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:naviController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply; however, this will not work because the NavigationController lies with the rootViewController (or current one shown), not the DetailViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can create instance of storyboard from storyboard name.once you have correct storyboard instance, get NavigationController from Its identifier, and detailviewController from its identifier. Push detailviewcontroller on Navigationviewcontroller.

get storyboard-- replace name of your storyboard in "MainSToryboard"

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = 
[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" 
                          bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

get instance of Navigationcontroller - replace identifier:

UINavigationController *navController  =(UINavigationController *) 
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navcontroller"];

get detailviewconrtoller :

```
UIViewController *detailvc=  
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profile"];
```

Push detail on current navigationcontroller:

```
[navController  pushViewController:detailvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: This produces the same issue I had before. Does not display anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate solution. The cause was because the incorrect view controller was being called by

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController.*
```

**The workaround is**:

In the primary view controller class, I passed the displayed viewcontroller into the delegate class. Then, from the child class I wanted to call, I referenced that view controller, and navigation controller, and it worked just fine. My final code is below:

```
// Create the detail View Controller
ProfileViewViewController *tempViewToShow = [del.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profile"];

// Set the user variable in the detail view controller
tempViewToShow.thisUser = self.postUser;

// Push the view controller into the navigation controller
// Note that del.currentNav comes from this code:
/*  
 *  In this class, create the delegate reference
 *  AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
 *  
 *  In the Delegate class, get the set the current navigation controller {let currentVC : UIViewController = passedInVC}
 *  self.currentNav = currentVC.navigationController;
 */
[del.currentNav pushViewController:tempViewToShow animated:YES];
```